# Bullet Physics Engine no longer on DRC Roadmap?

Tags: physics

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It appears the Bullet Physics Engine is no longer mentioned on the
DRC Roadmap.
http://gazebosim.org/wiki/DRC/Roadmap

Is this an oversight, or is Bullet out of the picture for the VRC?
Knowing the answer would be tremendously helpful, in guiding us as to whether to tune our controllers to work well in ODE, or hold off in hopes of a better physics engine.

Thanks,
Chris

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/913/bullet-physics-engine-no-longer-on-drc-roadmap?/) by [cga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/66/cga/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 223 on 2013-01-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I think it's still in the Gazebo roadmap.  They keep DRC specific things in the roadmap you linked.

http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Roadmap

---

Originally posted by [dcconner](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/47/dcconner/) with karma: 298 on 2013-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) on 2013-01-18**:
Indeed; Bullet integration is planned for Gazebo 1.5.  You can follow along with the pull requests that are adding Bullet support (e.g., most recently: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/217/bullet-integration-spawn-and-drop-simple/).